# Cannot create reports on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, reporting-services, reportserver

I am unable to create reports in Visual studio SSRS and get below error.

[image]

I tried running the query in SSMS and get no errors. I have Visual Studio Professional 2022 installed on my machine.
Any idea how this can be solved?

Thanks
AR

Comment: This is nothing to do with a query or SSMS. It's telling you that it cannot connect to the SSRS server. Check the project properties and make sure that it's set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in the error it says u need to set permissions for this process and also dont forget checking the "targetsetverurl" if its not valid. But priority should be setting permission for that.